# How to hide an image when the page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

With the following code when I refresh the page, the image id `imagen1` appears just down the image id `theImage`, but I want `imagen1` to disappear. How can I hide an image when the page refresh?

**HTML**

```html
<div id="column1">
    <img id="theImage" src="img/panta_de_sau.jpg">
    <div id="imagen" class="col-2">
        <article>
           <img class="light" id="imagen1" src="img/liceu1.jpg">
        </article>    
    </div> 
 </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
window.onload=function () {
    document.getElementById("theImage").style.display = "block";
    $(".ulmenu").click(function(){
        document.getElementById("theImage").style.display = "none";
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want the image to be visible when someone first visits the page and then removed if the page is refreshed? It looks like you are binding a click handler to an element to hid the containing div.

Comment: you would need to store it's state in something like localstorage so you can check the variable when the page reloads and reset it

Answer (score 0):

store the refresh in a cookie:

```
document.cookie = "browserRefreshed";
```

--check it

```
 if (document.cookie.indexOf("browserRefreshed") == -1)
  {

  }
 else
 {

 }
```